# Why isn't there a difference between the ceiling and floor operators in this example? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have to split a list in half, resulting in a tuple of the first half of the list and the second half of the list `(half1, half2)`. When the length of this list is odd, then I want to make `half1` contain more elements than `half2`.

```
 halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
 halve [] = ([],[])
 halve xs =
    if (((length(xs) `mod` 2)==1))
    then(take (ceiling(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs, drop(ceiling(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs)
    else ((take (floor(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs, drop (floor(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs))
 main = do
 putStrLn(show (halve [1,2,3])) gives me [1],[2,3] instead of [1,2],[3]
 putStrLn(show (halve [])) gives me an error
```

This makes me think that there is some truncation going on in the mod operation or ceiling operation. 
I know that for the error with putStrLn(show (halve [])), the interpreter doesn't know what the array is made of, but how can I make it so that the type does not matter? I would like that line to give me ([],[]).

Comment: 1) You don't need to explicitly parenthesize everything. Haskell is smart. Instead of writing `if (((length(xs) \`mod\` 2)==1))` you can simply write `if length xs \`mod\` 2 == 1` 2) Use `print` instead of `putStrLn (show ...)`. 3) Learn about function composition and application

Comment: And please observe that "gives me an error" is uninformative. There is not just one error, you know? And if you believe it or not, sometimes it is important to know **what** error you get.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem then you should either accept an answer or else provide your own answer and accept it. Do not edit your question and mention that it is solved. It's not helpful to other people. Also don't remove vital information from your question. It might make some answers appear out of context. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halve xs = let n = div (length xs + 1) 2
           in (take n xs, drop n xs)

-- or alternatively

halve :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halve xs = splitAt (div (length xs + 1) 2) xs
```

The `div` function rounds down (floors) positive quotients and rounds up (ceils) negative quotients:

```
div  5 2 =>  2
div -5 2 => -2
div  6 2 =>  3
div -6 2 => -3
```

The `halve` function works just as you would expect it to:

```
halve []     => ([], [])
halve [1..5] => ([1,2,3], [4,5])
halve [1..6] => ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

I don't see why you need an `if then else` branch. Your function is unnecessarily complicated.