# How do you specify any type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have to split a list in half, resulting in a tuple of the first half of the list and the second half of the list (half1, half2). When the length of this list is odd, then I want to make half1 contain more elements than half2. If given an empty list, I want a tuple of ([],[]). However, the following code gives me an error.

```
 halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
 halve [] = ([],[])
 halve xs =
    if (((length(xs) `mod` 2)==1))
    then(take (ceiling(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs, drop(ceiling(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs)
    else ((take (floor(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs, drop (floor(toRational(length(xs) `div` 2))) xs))
 main = do
 putStrLn(show (halve [1,2,3])) 
 putStrLn(show (halve [])) gives me an error
```

I think that for the error with putStrLn(show (halve [])), the interpreter doesn't know what the array is made of, but how can I make it so that the type does not matter so that line gives me ([],[]).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't there a difference between the ceiling and floor operators in this example? (Haskell)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257337/why-isnt-there-a-difference-between-the-ceiling-and-floor-operators-in-this-exa)

Comment: Haven't you already asked the exact same question before? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20257337/783743

Comment: Hey yeah, it's the same program, but different question about it.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem then you should either accept an answer or else provide your own answer and accept it. Do not edit your question and mention that it is solved. It's not helpful to other people. Also don't remove vital information from your question. It might make some answers appear out of context. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `[]` is polymorphic right? It's type is `[] :: [a]`. This combined with the fact that we use `Show` means that our type is `Show a => [a]`.

Now Haskell has no idea which `a` we want, and the choice matters! If `a` is a `Char` than this prints `("", "")`, if `a` isn't, it might print `([], [])`. So we have to decide what type we want to use.

A simple trick is that `[] :: String` is just `""`. So

```
putStrLn (show (halve ""))
```

Since `print` is the same behavior

```
print (halve "")
```

If we don't want to use `Char`, then we can just write

```
print (halve ([] :: [SomeType]))
```

Comment: You should probably remove the universal quantification from the type definition of `[]` so that you don't confuse the OP more than he already is.

Comment: @AaditMShah Fair enough, I usually like to be more explicit

Comment: I want it to print ([],[]), and I'm not sure what type to specify to get this.

Comment: @user2149780 THe bottom line

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.  You must specify what the list is of.  This is the way static typing works, ghc must know at compile time.  So you have to have something like this.

```
main = do                                                                           
    print (halve [1,2,3])                                                           
    print (halve ([] :: [Int]))
```

Also, I cleaned up your halve function.

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])                                                           
halve [] = ([],[])                                                                  
halve xs                                                                            
    | odd l         = splitAt ((l `div` 2) + 1) xs                                  
    | otherwise     = splitAt (l `div` 2) xs                                        
  where l = length xs
```

Comment: I wouldn't really call your function "clean". You're unnecessarily complicating things by using guards. Why not just define `halve` as `halve xs = let n = div (length xs + 1) 2 in (take n xs, drop n xs)`? Your code makes Haskell look clumsy.

Comment: An even shorter version would be: `halve xs = splitAt (div (length xs + 1) 2) xs`.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, your `halve` function is somewhat poorly written. You can make that function much shorter, like so:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halve xs = (take n xs, drop n xs) 
  where n = ceiling . (/2) . toRational . length $ xs
```

This relies on the fact that `take n []` == `drop n []` == `[]`.

Also, in Haskell, you don't need parentheses on function calls `f(a,b) == f a b`, and `g(f(x))` can be written as `g . f $ x`.

Finally, as others have mentioned, you need to specify the type of `[]` no that the compiler can find the appropriate show instance.

(A neat trick is that `print = putStrLn . show`)

```
main = do
  print $ halve [1,2,3]
  print $ halve ([] :: [Integer])
```

Comment: Even shorter version: `halve xs = let n = div (length xs + 1) 2 in (take n xs, drop n xs)`. See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20257470/783743

Comment: Even more shorter version: `halve xs = splitAt (div (length xs + 1) 2) xs`.

Comment: Nice short ones. I'll have to remember those.